# Algorithm for finding the smallest lists that together make up the target list

Tags: python, list, merge

Let's suppose I have the following:

```
{
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': [1, 5],
  'c': [3, 4, 5],
  'd': [1, 3, 5],
  'e': [4]
}
```

the desired result is `['a', 'c']`
because I want to find which arrays merged together (and removing the duplicates) forms `[1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Other than which arrays merged together forms the desired result, I also want to find the minimum arrays to merge to get the desired result (because for example also `['a', 'd', 'e']` gives the desired result, but `['a', 'c']` is a better solution)

PS. The dictionary above is just an example, the original one has a lot of keys and each key has hundreds of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be very elegant but it will be more efficient than brute forcing through all combinations.  It should perform in quadratic time as opposed to combinations which could become exponential depending on the number of entries and on the spread of data.

The following function finds a short solution. Most probably (but not necessarily) the shortest.

```
from collections import Counter

def findMerge(data,target):
    # identify candidate items (i.e. subsets of the target list)
    target     = set(target)
    candidates = {c:group for c,group in data.items() if target.issuperset(group)}
    
    # compute the overlap between candidates and check coverage
    counts = Counter( n for group in candidates.values() for n in group )
    if any(t not in counts for t in target): return [] 

    # identify candidates that are mandatory and the base set they form
    # (i.e. candidates that are the only ones with a given value)
    mandatory = { c:group for c,group in candidates.items()
                  if any(counts[n]==1 for n in group) }
    baseSet   = set().union(*mandatory.values())
    remaining = target - baseSet
    if not remaining: return list(mandatory)
   
    # identify potentially redundant candidates for remaining values
    redundant = [ (c,remaining.intersection(group))
                  for c,group in candidates.items() if c not in mandatory ]

    # remove redundant candidates (smallest first)
    # note: using combinations only on redundant keys may be affordable here
    #       and could be used to return all solutions or ensure shortest
    redundant = sorted(redundant,key=lambda cg:len(cg[1]))
    for r,rGroup in redundant:
        if all(counts[n]>1 for n in rGroup):
            counts.subtract(rGroup)
            del candidates[r]
        
    return list(candidates)
```

Output for a small sample:

```
data = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': [1, 5],
  'c': [3, 4, 5],
  'd': [1, 3, 5],
  'e': [4]
}

print(findMerge(data,[1,2,3,4,5])) # ['a', 'c']
```

For a larger sample, the time difference compared to combinations will be significant:

```
data = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': [1, 5, 0],
  'c': [3, 2, 5],
  'd': [1, 3, 5],
  'e': [4],
  'f': [1, 2, 5],
  'g': [1, 5, 8],
  'h': [3, 4, 7],
  'i': [1, 6, 5],
  'j': [4],
  'k': [9],
  'l': [1, 3, 5],
  'm': [4],
  'n': [1, 2, 5],
  'o': [1, 5, 8],
  'p': [3, 4, 7],
  'q': [1, 5, 8],
  'r': [3, 4, 7],
  's': [1, 6, 5],
  't': [4],
  'u': [9],
}

target = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(findMerge(data,target)) # ['b', 'c', 'q', 'r', 's', 'u']
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along this line should work. You will need to tweak a bit depending on whether you wanted it sorted or not, etc. This solution assumes order does not matter.

Prints solutions from smallest to largest:

```py
import itertools

input = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': [1, 5],
  'c': [3, 4, 5],
  'd': [1, 3, 5],
  'e': [4]
}

solution = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(1,len(input.keys())):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(input, i):
        pot = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(input[k] for k in combination)))
        if pot == solution:
            print("This is a solution:", combination)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I guess that itertools was the tool that I needed.